# What all the numbers in a 2x2 matrix represents in real world

Tags: matrices

I have a problem understanding what all numbers in a matrix actually represents in the physical world. My problem is stated below:

I have the following matrix, where $k$ represents a variable, for example permeability:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        k_{xx} & k_{xy} \\
        k_{yx} & k_{yy} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$k_{xx}$ represents the variable in the x-direction, while $k_{yy}$ represents the variable in the y-direction.

My question is: What does $k_{xy}$ and $k_{yx}$ represent?

Comment: What do you mean by the variable in the $x$-direction? Also, if you are the one who has the matrix, then surely you are the one who knows how it has been formed.

Comment: If the variable is permeablity, I mean that it represents the permeability in the x-direction. I am just wondering how we can generally understand the interpretation of such a matrix as I shown above.

Comment: We can't unless it has been specified how it has been constructed.

Comment: Okay. I only know that it is a rank 2 tensor (matrix) representing permeability.  I guess I would have to get more information about the matrix before I can say anything about what the different parts represents. Thanks for showing me that.

Comment: Is it a covariance matrix?